# Помогите импортировать в csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

```
#! usr/bin python3
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    search = soup.find('div', class_='search-total js-search-total')
    span = soup.find('span', class_='search-message js-page-title')
    spantext = span.text
    searchtext = search.text
    print(spantext, searchtext)

def save(searchtext, spantext, path):
    with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(('Название', 'Кол-во'))
        writer.writerow((spantext['Название'], searchtext['Кол-во']))

save ('project.csv')


def main():
    parse(get_html('http://www.abitant.com/catalogues/bra-i-nastennye-svetilniki/companies/robers'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: save() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'spantext' and 'path'
```

Ребята, не понимаю как сохранить данные в csv файл,помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Какие данные? Примеры из документации на модуль CSV просмотрены? В чем конкретно тогда проблема?

Comment: Да, документацию смотрел, но не разобрался.
Не удаётся сохранить файл в csv.

Comment: Какие именно данные не сохраняются? Сделайте минимальный пример где что-то не работает.

Comment: Не создаётся csv файл.

Comment: И еще раз: какие данные? Минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы в вопросе напишите.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, там же ошибка в коде просто в глаза бросается, что Вы пристали к человеку? :)

Comment: @andy.37 Я даже не буду смотреть код, который не смогу у себя проверить путем запуска, ну нет у меня Супа... Даже если был бы, данные от сервера могут быть разными и иногда будет работать, иногда нет.

Comment: Этот код не запускается, интерпретатор кидает экспшн. Кстати, soap - хороший, могу рекомендовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
save ('project.csv')
def save(searchtext, spantext, path):
```

Вам же ясно интерпретатор говорит: "пропущено 2 аргумента в функции save"

Почему Вы вообще вызываете ф-ю save в таком странном месте и без нужных аргументов? Где Вы возьмете эти аргументы в момент вызова?

Должно быть что то вроде:

```
def parse(...):
   ....
   print(...)
   save(searchetxt, spantext, 'project.csv')
```

Comment: Благодарю.
Затупил ...